# Reverse telnet software for Windows

Tags: windows, services

Can anyone recommend a reverse telnet (connect incoming TCP to a COM port) program for Windows?

Ideally it would run as a system service and listen on an array of TCP ports corresponding to the various COMn serial ports, but I'd also be happy with manually launching and a single port.

Solutions that require cygwin are acceptable.  I have `nc` but I don't know how to launch it to get bidirectional communications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *External Links* section of the "[COM port redirector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_port_redirector#External_links)" article on Wikipedia has a list of over 20 programs.

Comment: Thanks.  `socat` is promising.  Most of that page seems to be describing virtual ports, which is something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that although netcat requires separate file descriptors for read and write, `socat` can use a single descriptor.

`socat TCPv4-LISTEN:`*tcpportnum*`/dev/ttyS`*serialportnum*`,b`*baudrate*

works nicely.